# gdb watchpoint won't work when variable changes from going off end of array

Tags: c, gdb, watch, watchpoint

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ThingStruct {
    int arr[8];
    int after;
} Thing;

void foo(int i) {
    Thing thing;
    int* ip = &thing.after;
    thing.after = 12345;
    printf("beforehand\n");
    thing.arr[i] = 55;
    printf("done\n");
}

int main() {
    foo(8);
}
```

This code changes `thing.after` by accidentally going off the end of the array. I want to try to find the line where where `thing.after` is changing by using gdb. So I compile with -g , put a breakpoint on line 12, then put a watchpoint on `thing.after`, but the watchpoint doesn't trigger, even though putting a breakpoint on line 14 does show that `thing.after` did change.

I even tried taking the address of `thing.after` and setting a watchpoint on that, but it still does not trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Watch point needs to be re-added each time the `foo` function is entered (Note that, as you are watching the local variable, it will not be valid after the stack frame exits and will be automatically deleted after the `foo` returns). Also, if the watched variable changes on the current line to be executed, then the watch point is not getting triggered (not sure why). For me it works when I add the watch point `watch thing.after` just after entering foo when on line `int* ip = &thing.after;`. When I continue, the watch point hits 2 times.

Comment: `foo` is only called once in this test.

Comment: OK, it was 2 problems, the not triggering on the next line, and also in a much larger program it was putting the -g labels 1 or 2 lines offset, which had me confused thinking the watchpoint wasn't triggering at all.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which platform, what version of GDB, or what command you used to set the watchpoint.

Using gdb 7.9 on Ubuntu/x86_64, things work as I expect them to work:

```
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400538: file t.c, line 10.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, foo (i=8) at t.c:10
10          int* ip = &thing.after;
(gdb) watch thing.after
Hardware watchpoint 2: thing.after
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: thing.after

Old value = 4195712
New value = 12345
foo (i=8) at t.c:12
12          printf("beforehand\n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
beforehand
Hardware watchpoint 2: thing.after

Old value = 12345
New value = 55
foo (i=8) at t.c:14
14          printf("done\n");
```

(gdb) q